# Generate random values for golange

Tags: go, random, passwords

I need a random password generator for a project, I need to make 10 of them. I found this function (random), but when I run it in a loop, it generates the same passwords. I don't know what's the problem.

```
func main() {

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        a := random()
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}

func random() string {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    chars := []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + "0123456789")
    length := 10
    var b strings.Builder
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        b.WriteRune(chars[rand.Intn(len(chars))])
    }
    str := b.String()
    return str
}
```

Comment: You only seed a PRNG once.

Comment: If you really really want randoms, use a cryptographically secure random number generator. There should be plenty of questions on that. Those you don't need to seed; they'll generally use the system to initially seed themselves.

Comment: Re-seeding the PRNG every time is what does it. It runs fast enough that every time it gets the same seed, so you get the same value. `UnixNano` has nanosecond *granularity*, but not necessary nanosecond *precision*, that's OS-dependent. Just seed it once and re-use it, or (since this is for passwords) use `crypto/rand` and don't seed it at all.

Comment: Here is how you do this sort of thing securely using crypto/rand: https://go.dev/play/p/NdjFVLRJe2Z (if you really only want lower case characters change the encoding base from 62 to 36; these passwords word be *much* less secure).

Answer (score 0):

Adapting your example code and refactoring it a bit:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rp := newRandPass(rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())), 10, 10)
    fmt.Println(rp.passwords())
}

type RandPass struct {
    r   *rand.Rand
    num int
    len int
}

func newRandPass(r *rand.Rand, num, len int) *RandPass {
    return &RandPass{r, num, len}
}

func (r *RandPass) passwords() []string {
    chars := []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + "0123456789")
    passwords := make([]string, r.num)
    for i := 0; i < r.num; i++ {
        s := make([]rune, r.len)
        for j := 0; j < r.len; j++ {
            s[j] = chars[r.r.Intn(len(chars))]
        }
        passwords[i] = string(s)
    }
    return passwords
}
```

> - 

```
$ go run .
[rt97kzwjwe 5ziim05exh 40dfly93et v5tga5bwv9 avf2p2dpjx hsz4lca0jv 8r7bvvtu5l 9byf3mjq6r sdr2mpo54g cjx4mq6c0t]
```